# Could not compile a "hello world" cpp in my OSX

Tags: c++, macos

I wrote a hello world program on my mac, but when I compiled it, the compiler output an error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "std::__1::locale::use_facet(std::__1::locale::id&) const", referenced from:
      std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >& std::__1::__put_character_sequence<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, char const*, unsigned long) in endian0-654ab7.o
  "std::__1::ios_base::getloc() const", referenced from:
      std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >& std::__1::__put_character_sequence<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, char const*, unsigned long) in endian0-654ab7.o
  "std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >::__init(unsigned long, char)", referenced from:
      std::__1::ostreambuf_iterator<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> > std::__1::__pad_and_output<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >(std::__1::ostreambuf_iterator<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >, char const*, char const*, char const*, std::__1::ios_base&, char) in endian0-654ab7.o
  "std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >::~basic_string()", referenced from:
      std::__1::ostreambuf_iterator<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> > std::__1::__pad_and_output<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >(std::__1::ostreambuf_iterator<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >, char const*, char const*, char const*, std::__1::ios_base&, char) in endian0-654ab7.o
  "std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >::sentry::sentry(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&)", referenced from:
      std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >& std::__1::__put_character_sequence<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, char const*, unsigned long) in endian0-654ab7.o
  "std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >::sentry::~sentry()", referenced from:
      std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >& std::__1::__put_character_sequence<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, char const*, unsigned long) in endian0-654ab7.o
  "std::__1::cout", referenced from:
      _main in endian0-654ab7.o
  "std::__1::ctype<char>::id", referenced from:
      std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >& std::__1::__put_character_sequence<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, char const*, unsigned long) in endian0-654ab7.o
  "std::__1::locale::~locale()", referenced from:
      std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >& std::__1::__put_character_sequence<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, char const*, unsigned long) in endian0-654ab7.o
  "std::__1::ios_base::__set_badbit_and_consider_rethrow()", referenced from:
      std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >& std::__1::__put_character_sequence<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, char const*, unsigned long) in endian0-654ab7.o
  "std::__1::ios_base::clear(unsigned int)", referenced from:
      std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >& std::__1::__put_character_sequence<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, char const*, unsigned long) in endian0-654ab7.o
  "std::terminate()", referenced from:
      ___clang_call_terminate in endian0-654ab7.o
  "___cxa_begin_catch", referenced from:
      std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >& std::__1::__put_character_sequence<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, char const*, unsigned long) in endian0-654ab7.o
      ___clang_call_terminate in endian0-654ab7.o
  "___cxa_end_catch", referenced from:
      std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >& std::__1::__put_character_sequence<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, char const*, unsigned long) in endian0-654ab7.o
  "___gxx_personality_v0", referenced from:
      std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >& std::__1::__put_character_sequence<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, char const*, unsigned long) in endian0-654ab7.o
      std::__1::ostreambuf_iterator<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> > std::__1::__pad_and_output<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >(std::__1::ostreambuf_iterator<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >, char const*, char const*, char const*, std::__1::ios_base&, char) in endian0-654ab7.o
      Dwarf Exception Unwind Info (__eh_frame) in endian0-654ab7.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

This is the program:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    cout<< "hello world";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: How do you build your program?

Comment: I use `gcc -o endian endian0.cpp` as I normally use in linux

Comment: As per trojanfoe below, try clang++.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like you are missing (failing to link) the C++ runtime library.  While you don't show the command line you used to compile and link the program, this should do it:

```
$ clang++ -o hello hello.cpp
```

Comment: I use the command `gcc -o endian endian0.cpp`,  but why the compiler does not detect it is a c++ file?

Comment: @haolly It does; the issue is that as you didn't use `g++` it doesn't know to include the C++ runtime library.

Comment: I seem to recall reading `g++` was just a front end for `clang++` on Mac, so this is probably the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this too. This is use to link the library to linker. Here it is c++ runtime library.

```
clang -l c++ -o hello hello.cpp
```

**I would prefer to use clang++.**

> The -l flag does not change standards conformance, it is used to
>   specify what libraries to link with. here -l c++ means libc++ to link.
>   Whenever you required libstdc++ library then it will not work. You
>   have to put -l stdc++.So that is the better practice to use the
>   clang++ that will manage all of the required system libraries for c++.

Comment: "I would prefer" is an opinion. It would be much better if you could replace that with some facts about why it is the better choice.

Comment: The -l flag does not change standards conformance, it is used to specify what libraries to link with. here -l c++ means libc++ to link. Whenever you required libstdc++ library then it will not work. You have to put -l stdc++.So that is the better practice to use the clang++ that will manage all of the required system libraries for c++.